How to formulate the single-pair shortest-paths problem as a linear program. ("Introduction to Algorithms Third Edition" by CLRS.)
I am reading "Introduction to Algorithms Third Edition" by CLRS.
The authors wrote how to formulate the single-pair shortest-paths problem as a linear program.
The authors explain why the linear program maximizes an objective function when it is supposed to compute shortest paths in the following figure.
But I think the authors didn't prove that the optimal objective value for (29.44), (29,45) and (29.46) is equal to the shortest-path weight $\delta(s,t)$.
So I tried to prove that the optimal objective value for (29.44), (29,45) and (29.46) is equal to the shortest-path weight $\delta(s,t)$.
My proof:

Let $p=\langle s, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_k, t\rangle$ be the shortest path.
Let $\overline{d_u}$ be the shortest-path weight $\delta(s,u)$ for each $u\in V$.
Then, obviously $(\overline{d_u})_{u\in V}$ is a feasible solution for the linear program.
Let $(\overline{d'_u})_{u\in V}$ be one of the optimal solutions for the linear program.
Assume that $\overline{d'_t}>\overline{d_t}$.
Then, $$\overline{d'_{v_k}}+w(v_k,t)\geq\min_{u:(u,t)\in E}\{\overline{d'_u}+w(u,t)\}\geq\overline{d'_t}>\overline{d_t}=\min_{u:(u,t)\in E}\{\overline{d_u}+w(u,t)\}=\overline{d_{v_k}}+w(v_k,t).$$
So, $\overline{d'_{v_k}}>\overline{d_{v_k}}$.
By the same argument, we know that $\overline{d'_{v_{k-1}}}>\overline{d_{v_{k-1}}}$.
By the same argument, we know that $\overline{d'_{v_{k-2}}}>\overline{d_{v_{k-2}}}$.
$\cdots$
By the same argument, we know that $\overline{d'_{v_1}}>\overline{d_{v_1}}$.
By the same argument, we know that $\overline{d'_{s}}>\overline{d_{s}}$.
This implies $0=\overline{d'_{s}}>\overline{d_{s}}=0$.
This is a contradiction.
So, $(\overline{d_u})_{u\in V}$ is one of the optimal solutions for the linear program.

I am afraid if my argment contains errors.

